# build issue on qt/c++ on a struct definition which exist

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qt5

I do have a build issue as shown below :

```
In file included from ../../../connect.proto/Applications/connect/main.cpp:10:
In file included from ../../../connect.proto/Applications/connect/mainui.h:19:
In file included from ../../../connect.proto/Applications/connect/treewidget.h:21:
../../../connect.proto/Applications/connect/framework.h:24:5: error: unknown type name 'MY_Box_Button_t'
    MY_Box_Button_t OverwriteOption;
```

Strange things is the the MY_Box_Button_t is include in the treewidget.h and this file is declared in the framework.h at the beginning.

As my app is using various h and cpp, I suspect that another include already include the header which contain the definition of MY_Box_Button_t

I use it in another part of the app and it's works.. I can't really see the diff.

Any idea to debug ? thx

Comment: Why not just include the header that defines that type

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf this is what I have done. the header is included inside the framework.h. this is why I'm lost. the right header is included in the framework.h

Comment: Is the file with the definition directly included in the file that is giving the error?  In general it's bad practice to assume that another header already includes the file.  Each file should be able to compile on its own.

Comment: Don't you have any kind of cyclic dependencies between header files, that prevent proper expansion of considered `#include`?

Comment: @Werkov. It's my thought... I'm ready to take a pencil and paper to check it one by one...

Comment: @Seb, I'd recommend `gcc -E` to see preprocessor output, it might be more expressive/accurate than pencil-paper solution :-)